# Is the miners address part of the block or the block header?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, block-header

Should the following be sufficient merkle root, block number, previous block hash, timestamp and nonce?

Comment: Sufficient for what? Your question is incomplete, it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to find the miner's address, you will need the full block, not just the header.

The miner's address will be transaction 0 of the block, also known as the [coinbase transaction](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/coinbase-transaction).  Like all the other transactions, it is included in the [Merkle Root](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/merkle-root) in the block header, but not in the block header itself.